# Prove proposition regarding connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space, $A \subseteq B \subseteq \overline{A} \subseteq X$, $A$ is connected ($\overline{A}$ denotes the closure of $A$). Prove that $B$ is connected.

I've just started my attempt of proving this, by the way.

Comment: A useful characterisation of connectedness is that every continuous map to a discrete space is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f:B\to\{0,1\}$ is continuous. We can assume that $f(a)=0$ for some point $a\in A$. As $A$ is connected, the restriction $f|_A:A\to\{0,1\}$ is constant, so $f(A)=\{0\}$. By continuity of $f$ we have $$f(B)= f\left(\overline A^B\right)\subseteq\overline{f(A)}=\overline{\{0\}}=\{0\}$$
where $\overline A^B$ denotes the closure of $A$ in the subspace topology of $B$. This equals $\overline A^B=\overline A\cap B=B$. So $f$ is constant, too.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $B$ is not connected. Then $B\subset U\cup V$, where $U$, $V$ open and $$U\cap V=\varnothing,$$ while $$B\cap U\ne\varnothing,\,\, B\cap V\ne\varnothing.$$ 
Note that $U\cap V=\varnothing$, then $V\subset X\smallsetminus U$, and as $X\smallsetminus U$ is closed, then $$\overline{V}\subset X\smallsetminus U \tag{1}.$$

As $A$ is connected, then either $A\cap U=\varnothing$ or $A\cap V=\varnothing$. Without loss of generality assume that $A\cap U=\varnothing$, and hence $A\subset V$. But this implies that $\overline{A}\subset \overline{V}\subset X\smallsetminus U$, due to $(1)$. But this implies that
$$
B\subset \overline{A}\subset \overline{V}\subset X\smallsetminus U,
$$
which contradicts our initial assumption that $B\cap U\ne\varnothing$.